# my LND is not 100% up and want to check how long can I stay offline in each open channel

Tags: lightning-network-daemon, channels

I'm newbie and running LND and few channels. But my power supply is not stable and it goes offline many times in a week. sometimes even for 8 hours. How do I check if the time locks of my channels allows me few days or even a week to stay offline with my node and still not loose channel balance if a peer tries to cheat me.
I am using RTL but I see so many keywords and units I cannot easily understand. The docs dont easily explain either how to understand lncli output. Like I cannot understand output of `lncli listchannels`